# Use custom transport layer protocol in Node.js

Tags: node.js, networking

I've wanted to experiment with creating a transport layer protocol in Node.js, but I couldn't find anything in the documentation used to interact directly with the IP protocol. I tried skimming through the code for the implementation of UDP to no avail. Can anyone lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a c++/c module for Node, as node does not expose an API for accessing raw sockets.

There is a npm package that can do this for you.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/raw-socket